# pythonでseleniumを用いてhtmlを読み込む方法

Tags: python

http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/bestsellers/gift-cards/ref=zg_bs_nav_0
以上のサイトから商品のランキングを取得しようと考えています。

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path)
start_url = 'http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/bestsellers/gift-cards/ref=zg_bs_nav_0'
driver.get('start_url')
page_source = driver.page_source
html = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
print html
```

このコードを実行した結果、`<html><head></head><body></body></html>`としか返ってこず途方に暮れています。Javascriptによるレンダリングのタイミング等もよく理解していないため解説していただけたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

`driver.get('start_url')` を　`driver.get(start_url)` にしてもダメですか？

あと、質問本文中のHTMLタグはそのままだと表示されないので、バッククォート (`) で囲んであげて下さい。
（編集しようとしたのですが、編集の文字数が少なすぎるとエラーが出てしまいました・・・）